# using sorted(list, key=function()) with variables

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda, iteration

**this is difficult for me to put together in a sentence so bear with me please**, but in essence, i am looking for a way to use sorted(list, key=function) where the function can have 2 variables.
For example,
lets say i was iterating through a list of items, and had a separate list waiting...

```
separate_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

iter_through_this = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
```

but What I need to do is:

```
for ITEM in iter_through_this:
    print sorted(separate_list, key=(lambda it, n: ITEM % ...
```

the ellipsis is where I need help, how can I successfully sort this list (multiple times, for each iteration), based on the item itarated?

I am trying to sort based on `(i in separate_list) <modulo> (i in iter through this)`

Comment: The function can't actually have two parameters, because where would the other value come from? `sorted` isn't going to know what value you want passed as the argument. If you already _had_ a two-parameter function lying around, and just wanted to "fix" the value of one of the arguments, you can do that with `partial`, or just with a lambda that takes one argument and calls the real function (`lambda x: real_func(x, y)`). But in this case, just don't define the function with two parameters and the problem doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `ITEM` as a closure:

```
for item in iter_through_this:
    print sorted(separate_list, key=lambda n: item % n)
```

Here `n` is passed in by `sorted`, but `item` is resolved from the parent scope.